# Counting instances of a value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, counting

Homework. Dice Game. I've got an array that represents five rolls of a die. Consider:
`diceRoll[] = {6,3,3,4,5}`. I would LIKE to create a SECOND array that has the counts of values from one to six contained in `diceRoll[]`, (e.g., `occurence[] = {0,0,2,1,1,1}` for the `diceRoll[]` above.) but I fear I'm getting lost in nested loops and can't seem to figure out which value I ~should~ be returning. `occurence[]` is a global variable, and the intent is that the array will contain six values...the count of ones (at index [0]), twos (at [1]), threes (at [2]), etc.

So Far:

```
 for(i=1;i<7;i++)   /* die values 1 - 6
    {
       for(j=0;j<diceRoll.length;j++)  /* number of dice
       {
          if (diceRoll[j] == i)  /* increment occurences when die[j] equals 1, then 2, etc.
             occurence = occurence + 1;
       }
    }
    return occurence;
    }
```

I cannot, however, get the occurence=occurence+1 to work. `bad operand types for binary operator` is my most common error. I suspect I need to increment `occurence` OUTSIDE one or both of the for loops, but I'm lost.

Guidance? or perhaps the one-line easy way to do this?
d

Comment: Have you heard of ++? Makes your code look a WHOLE lot more professional.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<6;i++)   /* die values 1 - 6
{
 occurence[diceRoll[i]]++;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I have to do this is to create the second array in order so that 
occurrence[0] = # of 1's occurrence[1] = # of 2's and so on. Then this becomes a 1 loop method.

```
//method to return number of occurrences of the numbers in diceRolls
int[] countOccurrences(int[] diceRolls) {
    int occurrence[] = new int[6]; //to hold the counts

    for(int i = 0; i < diceRolls.length; i++) { //Loop over the dice rolls array
       int value = diceRolls[i]; //Get the value of the next roll
       occurence[value]++; //Increment the value in the count array this is equivalent to occurrence[value] = occurrence[value] + 1;
       //occurrence[diceRolls[i]]++; I broke this into two lines for explanation purposes
    }

    return occurrence; //return the counts 
}
```

EDIT:

Then to get the count for any particular value use `occurrence[value-1]`

Comment: Thanks, @twain249. I'm a little confused where I would insert this...the { at the end of the first line is throwing me off. Is this supposed to be a new method to which I would PASS my dice array? Where does occurence get incremented...or does this code simply count different values in diceRolls as it cycles through all five? I'm new...I get confused easily. :)

Comment: I wrote this as a method that you would pass your dice array to. So you could call it like `int occurrence[] = new int[6]; occurrence = countOccurrences(diceRolls);` but you could also use this multiple times. If you only need to count it once you should only need the loop and it would replace your snippet of code. I'll add comments to the code to show you what it's doing.

Comment: SO clear. I play with code now. Thank you very very very much! This is starting to gel in my brain.